# Take random substrings from genome after analysis of the random positions

Tags: regex, perl, split

I want to generate a list of random numbers, before comparing them to a list of ranges from one file. If a number lies in one of the ranges, i want to extract a substring from a string in another file, and printing them all out. I want to end up with exactly 749 random substrings in the outputfile. I have combined various pieces of code and it is outputting the correct data, but not the correct number of substrings. I believe the count i have applied of 749 occurs before the final if rule to check if it is in the ranges. I could obviously use a larger count and then manually select the first 749, however the range analysis seems to sort them numerically and so i wouldn't be taking truly random samples.

Edit: I have tried to  change the code to accommodate the random numbers into the ranges from each line in file 1, however i get a huge output (152000) lines of the same substring, code is at the bottom.

If it helps i have put some example file data below:

File1:

```
517 1878 forward
2156 3289 forward
3670 3915 forward
3912 5024 forward
5037 6968 forward
7005 9674 forward
```

File2:

```
>gi|385195117|emb|HE681097.1| Staphylococcus aureus subsp. aureus HO 5096 0412 complete genome
CGATTAAAGATAGAAATACACGATGCGAGCAATCAAATTTCATAACATCACCATGAGTTTGGTCCGAAGCATGAGTGTTTACAATGTTTGAATACCTTATACAGTTCTTATACATACCGATTAAAGATAGAAATACACGATGCGAGCAATCAAATTTCATAACATCACCATGAGTTTGGTCCGAAGCATGAGTGTTTACAATGTTTGAATACCTTATACAGTTCTTATACATACCGATTAAAGATAGAAATACACGATGCGAGCAATCAAATTTCATAACATCACCATGAGTTTGGTCCGAAGCATGAGTGTTTACAATGTTTGAATACCTTATACAGTTCTTATACATAC
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

chdir '/Users/edwardtickle/Documents';

open my $fh, '<', 'CC22rangesCDS.txt';

my @file1;
while (<$fh>) {
push @file1, [ split ];
}

my $size       = 21;
my $count      = 749;
my $min_length = ( $count - 1 ) * ( 2 * $size - 1 ) + $size;

open my $out, '>', 'randomnumberoutput.txt';

open $fh, '<', 'EMRSA-15.fasta';

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
next unless $line =~ /^([ATCG]+)/;

my $genome = $1;

if ( $min_length > length $genome ) {
    warn "Line $., Genome too small:  Must be $min_length, not ", length($genome), "\n";
    next;
}

my @pos = ( 0 .. length($genome) - 1 - ( $size - 1 ) );

for ( 1 .. $count ) {
    my $index = int rand @pos;
    my $pos   = $pos[$index];

    my $min = $index - ( $size - 1 );
    $min = 0 if $min < 0;
    splice @pos, $min, $size + $index - $min;

    for my $file1 (@file1) {

    my $substring = substr ($genome, $pos, $size);

    if ( $pos >= $file1->[0] and $pos <= $file1->[1] ) {

    print $out "$substring\n";
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

Un-working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

chdir '/Users/edwardtickle/Documents';

open my $fh, '<', 'CC22rangesCDS.txt';

my @file1;
while (<$fh>) {
push @file1, [ split ];
}

my $size       = 21;
my $count      = 749;

open my $out, '>', 'randomtestingoutput.txt';

open $fh, '<', 'EMRSA-15.fasta';

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
next unless $line =~ /^([ATCG]+)/;

my $genome = $1;

for my $file1 (@file1) {

my $range = ($file1->[1] - $file1->[0]);
my $minimum = $file1->[0];

my $position = int(rand($range)) + $minimum;

for ( 1 .. $count ) {

    my $substring = substr ($genome, $position, $size);

    print $out "$substring\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

I am really struggling with this so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your first line mentions you want to generate random numbers. You can always generate random numbers within the required range instead of generating numbers without limit and discarding the ones outside your range.

The rand() function let's you specify the upper and lower limits.

Something like this:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
  use strict;
  use warnings;

  my $range = 100;

  my $random_number = int(rand($range));

  print $random_number . "\n";
```

Refer the rand() function manual [here](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/rand_function.html)

Comment: I have tried using the manual to set the ranges according to the array of ranges from file1 and i have put the code into my original post, it still doesn't work as intended though. Cheers for your help.